# Qt & SSL, Handshake failed

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, windows-7, openssl

I have a problem. I've made a Qt application which is connecting to a https site.
On my working machine, everything works fine. When I try to test my application on a clean Windows 7 machine, I observed the following issue:

After I have installed a **fresh Win7 machine** (installed all updates), after starting my application, I get a **SSL Handshake failed error**, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList)) is emitted with two empty error strings and  **error = QSslError::NoError**.
I was really searching the whole day why this happens, also could reproduce it with examples\network\securesocketclient\release\securesocketclient and domain "google.com".

Now, I found out, that once I have started the internet explorer accessing https://www.google.com, my application is also working as expected and no further handshake errors are coming.

BTW, it does not matter which site you are accessing - this is not related to google.com.

Can someone explain to me why this happens? Is it a bug in OpenSSL, or Qt, or both?

**UPDATE**

I found a way to live with that issue for myself, implementing the following ignore logic:

```
QSslError ignoreNOErrors(QSslError::NoError);

foreach(QSslError error, errors)
    if(error.error() != QSslError::NoError)
        qDebug() << error.errorString();

QList<QSslError> expectedSslErrors;
expectedSslErrors.append(ignoreNOErrors);
reply->ignoreSslErrors(expectedSslErrors);
```

Thanks

Comment: Ok, seems nobody has a good idea. How about adding a root certificate, like the one from GeoTrust (https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/) into the socket's CA certificate database using http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsslsocket.html#addCaCertificate ? At least, it sounds like an reasonable workaround. Any thought?

Answer (score 26):

You could ignore certificate verify using QSslConfiguration::setPeerVerifyMode():

```
QSslConfiguration conf = request.sslConfiguration();
conf.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
request.setSslConfiguration(conf);
```

Comment: what happen? I get this problem when I try to connect to a remote address but it works fine to localhost.

Comment: Can't you just do `sslSocket->setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone)` without getting the ssl configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue on Mac with Qt 5.5 and 5.6. When I upgraded to 5.7 it is solved. Hope it may help if you are still facing this issue.

Comment: Any idea if the issue still persists in 5.9.4?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Qt [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-7200)

[This is padding for SO :D]